# How to clear libgdx listeners

Tags: java, libgdx

So in menu i have 3 buttons and all are with the same code. For the topic only important thing is

```
button2.addListener(new InputListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y,
    int pointer, int button) {
        game.setGame();
        dispose();
    return true;
    }
});
```

Then everything is going fine until:

```
button3.clearListeners(); // MainMenu.java:174 line in exeption
```

and then exeption pops out:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid between begin/end.
at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.DelayedRemovalArray.clear(DelayedRemovalArray.java:125)
at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Actor.clearListeners(Actor.java:261)
at com.racostyle.avdelux.MainMenu.dispose(MainMenu.java:174)
at com.racostyle.avdelux.MainMenu$3.touchDown(MainMenu.java:123)
at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.InputListener.handle(InputListener.java:55)
at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Actor.notify(Actor.java:165)
at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Actor.fire(Actor.java:136)
at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage.touchDown(Stage.java:277)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglInput.processEvents(LwjglInput.java:300)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:200)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:114)
```

EDIT: if i don't remove listeners they are still active and can be clickable, afc with exeptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're calling `MainMenu.dispose` within an `actor.touchdown` listener. `MainMenu.dispose` clears all listeners on a button.  LIBGX won't allow that.

Why?  Because LIBGDX is in the process of calling touch events on a lot of actors.  You really don't want your game functioning different depending on the order buttons were added to your stage.

So, call clear listeners somewhere else.

Since you're doing this within a dispose method anyway, I'd suggest NOT removing your button listeners at all, as the actor you've registered listeners for should not be used again.

Answer (score -1):

Its not allowed to just call clearListeners() without event;

Will you post your codes in jsfiddle.. i will try to debug it and add some codes..
Thanks ..

Comment: as i see jsfiddle is for javascript not for java?

but for that clear listeners. It clears all other listeners, so in button1 and button2. Problem is just on last one, which is clicked/touched

Comment: May ask what is button 3 do?? It will exit everything right

Comment: button calls new screen via backbone class (extends Game class) and removes current screen. But there is no problem. Problem is if i leave that listeners garbage collector wont remove them (i have tryed), so i have "ghost buttons" on screen and becouse of that i cant make movement which relays on touch events.

Comment: i have found a solution. I think it is just a temporaty solution, becouse i still have to find why i was getting exeptions.

Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(null);